# How to create directional light shadow in Three.JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to create shadows from a `DirectionalLight`?

If I use `SpotLight` then I see a shadow, but if I use `DirectionalLight` it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried and that didn't work?

Comment: @mrdoob I tried everything, but still doesn't works. Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4uqE/1/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, you most definitely *can* use directional lights to cast shadows. You need to make sure you are not using `MeshBasicMaterial` as they don't support shadows. Use `MeshLambertMaterial` or `MeshPhongMaterial` instead.

You need to enable shadows for the renderer with something along these lines:

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

renderer.shadowCameraNear = 3;
renderer.shadowCameraFar = camera.far;
renderer.shadowCameraFov = 50;

renderer.shadowMapBias = 0.0039;
renderer.shadowMapDarkness = 0.5;
renderer.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
renderer.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
```

And then you must enable shadow casting and shadow receiving per object and per light so you would have

```
dirLight.castShadow = true;
object.castShadow = true;
otherObject.receiveShadow = true;
```

Then, *if* the light and objects are placed at appropriate positions. `dirLight` will cause the shadow of `object` to be cast against `otherObject`.

**[EDIT]:** Here is a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4uqE/5)** for anyone looking to do something similar.

Comment: Yes it does, in your fiddle you have your directional light positioned inside of your cube. Here is the same fiddle with the light moved up and out of the cube. http://jsfiddle.net/Q4uqE/5/

Comment: How comes it that you have to move the light? From the Three.js doc: "Creates a light that shines from a specific direction not from a specific position.", changing position.x should just change the direction?

Comment: Shouldn't the shadowCameraNear, shadowCameraFar, shadowCameraFov, shadowMapBias, shadowMapDarkness, shadowMapWidth and shadowMapHeight parameters be set on the light not the renderer?

Comment: Do you know why `light.shadowCameraVisible` doesn't do anything in this forked example? http://jsfiddle.net/Q4uqE/566/

Comment: Your demo no longer works because the FOV of the directional light shadow camera has shrunken by default after r74. As Drew Noakes' answer mentions, you have to scale this FOV _at least as large as your object_: [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rxsrmL8/1).

Answer (score 53):

Be aware that shadow maps are scale dependent. I'm working on a scene where the unit distance represents one metre, and my objects are around 0.4 metres large. This is quite small by Three.js standards. If you have this situation too, then you can take a few important steps:

- Ensure the shadow camera's near/far planes are reasonable given your scene's dimensions.
- Ensure the shadow camera top/left/bottom/right values are not too large, otherwise each shadow 'pixel' may be so large that you don't even notice the shadow in your scene.

Let's look at how to do this.

#### Debugging

Be sure to turn on the debug rendering per light via [`CameraHelper`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/CameraHelper):

```
scene.add(new THREE.CameraHelper(camera))
```

Or in older versions of the Three.js:

```
light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
```

This will show you the volume over which the shadow is being calculated. Here is an example of what that might look like:

[image]

Notice the near and far planes (with black crosses), and the top/left/bottom/right of the shadow camera (outer walls of the yellow box.) You want this box to be tight around whatever objects you are going to have in shadow — possibly even tighter than I'm showing here.

#### Code

Here are some snippets of code that might be useful.

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set(0, 2, 2);
light.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
light.shadowCameraVisible = true; // only for debugging
// these six values define the boundaries of the yellow box seen above
light.shadowCameraNear = 2;
light.shadowCameraFar = 5;
light.shadowCameraLeft = -0.5;
light.shadowCameraRight = 0.5;
light.shadowCameraTop = 0.5;
light.shadowCameraBottom = -0.5;
scene.add(light);
```

Make sure some object(s) cast shadows:

```
object.castShadow = true;
```

Make sure some object(s) receive shadows:

```
object.receiveShadow = true;
```

Finally, configure some values on the `WebGLRenderer`:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
```

Comment: Is there a trick to make `light.shadowCameraVisible = true` work? It doesn't seem to do anything in this forked example (from the accepted answer above): http://jsfiddle.net/Q4uqE/566/

Comment: In recent Three.js versions one should use [CameraHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/CameraHelper) instead of `light.shadowCameraVisible = true`: `scene.add(new THREE.CameraHelper(camera))`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this.

Comment: Your explanation helped me heaps. Thanks a lot!
It's probably worth mentioning that the CameraHelper should point to the camera of the light source, like this: `scene.add(new THREE.CameraHelper(light.shadow.camera));`

Comment: Note that in the R160 version, the value is light.shadow.camera.left instead of light.shadowCameraLeft (and the others are changed as well).

Answer (score 0):

In r139.2 the attribues has been change to:

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; //THREE.BasicShadowMap | THREE.PCFShadowMap |  THREE.VSMShadowMap | THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap

renderer.shadowMap.soft = true;
renderer.shadowMap.bias = -0.0001;
renderer.shadowMap.darkness = 1;
renderer.shadowMap.width = 2048;
renderer.shadowMap.height = 2048;
```

sample:

```
const spotLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
spotLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(spotLight);
spotLight.position.set(0, 8, 0);


//Object cast shadow
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00}) );
cube.castShadow = true;
scene.add(cube);


//Plane floor receive shadows
const planeShadow = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()); //Material they have to be MeshPhongMaterial

planeShadow.name = "FloorShadow";
planeShadow.renderOrder = -2;
planeShadow.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
planeShadow.receiveShadow = true;
planeShadow.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(planeShadow);
```

If you need more info or other example, you can see this link [https://sbcode.net/threejs/directional-light-shadow/]