# Casting Shadows

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I saw this example talking about shadows: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/01/20/casting-shadows/.

I have tried here and I'm in trouble here... I put another cube like a wall... But the light is passing through that and the shadow too. How can I control the light to not pass to other side?

I put this question in the blog and I received the following response:
"unfortunatly you cant. Those lights and shadows dont obey physical laws. They are just tricks which makes it appears a bit real. Those limitations allows to get real time rendering too"

Is the information correct? Is there another way to do what I want?

Comment: That information is correct. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure mrdoob know's better than I do about this. But there is a link to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742149/how-to-create-directional-light-shadow-in-three-js/10904641#10904641) that might help you as well. One thing that got me for a while is that you must enable the overall shadow map then enable *shadow casting* and *shadow receiving* per object. Also I set my lights to .castShadow = true as well.

Comment: How can I enable shadow receiving per object? Is there some example?

Comment: I looked the examples webgl_shading_physical.html and webgl_shadowmap.html. And I didn't find how to control which shadow appear in a specific superficie. Is it possible?