# How to add appropriate light in the scene?

Tags: model, three.js, light, collada

In my project, I added several models and other geometry objects, and I could move camera to scan in the scene, but when I added lights as below, the model didn't show as it was. How should I add appropriate lights to suit well with models in the scene.

```
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// add directional light source
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,2);
directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

 var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
directionalLight1.position.set(-1, -1, -1).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight1);
```

Comment: Maybe it would be more appropriate to post this in the gamedev branch of stack overflow: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

That is going to be some pretty dark ambient light. I would recommend a value somewhere higher, closer to 0x555555 or more. Also, you are adding the directional light to your scene, but you are setting the positions of your directional lights very close to the origin of the scene.

You see `directionalLight.position` is a `THREE.Vector3` object and you are calling the .set() method of the vector object, then simply normalizing the result. Is your object larger than a unit or so? And is it at the origin? If so I am betting your directional light is inside your object. A 3D model is not going to look right with only ambient lighting. Instead I would recommend you do something like this:

```
        var originVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
        var ambLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
        scene.add(ambLight);

        var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF);
        dirLight.position.x = -200;
        dirLight.position.y = 200;
        dirLight.position.z = 150;
        dirLight.lookAt(originVector);
        scene.add(dirLight);
```

If you need shadows I refer you to this question I have previously answered about [Enabling Shadows in Three.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742149/how-to-create-directional-light-shadow-in-three-js/10904641#10904641). And here is a demo I made a while back that should show you the result of the above lighting code: [Lighting Cube Acceleration Demo](http://cmg0030.zxq.net/threejs/acclDemo).

Comment: hi, i can't find any docs about this like i know directionLight but where are you getting position, nomralize() method (somwhere else i saw it)...I wish i could find jquery style docs somewhere.

Comment: Position is a THREE.Vector3 object and normalize() belong to that class (or Vector2, Vector4). There is a plethora of docs, just need to look for it. http://threejs.org/docs/